# Return the "dictionary" keys based on substring

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am facing the following problem:
I have a list of diameters that are presented as
"Ø" + **number**
OR
**number** + "DN"

I need, based on this **number** to look for its equivalent value (something like a dictionary key) in another excel tab.
Besides the fact that I have to search for a substring, another problem I tried to solve by using "CELL("contents", array) is the fact that the values I use to get the key in the table are already formulas.

You will find attached my tentatives in the excel
[image]
I am not very good with excel, so if someone can help me I would be very grateful :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the numeric component of each cell, you can just use an `IF` and the various string functions like `LEFT` and `LEN`. Then once you get the component, you can use a simple `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` function.

For example:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT($F5, LEN($F5)-1))),
VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT($F5, LEN($F5)-1)),$A$2:$B$5,2,0),
VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT($F5, LEN($F5)-2)),$A$2:$B$5,2,0))
```

Another way is to just wrap the `VLOOKUP` in an `IFERROR`, and that way you avoid the original test.

[image]